# Serialisation / Deserialisation in CockrochDB from Key / Value to Relational

Tags: cockroachdb

I read a blog about CockroachDB that mentioning it is an interesting Key/Value - Relational DB hybrid.

I tried to read the documentation of the CockroachDB and if I understood the architecture documentation, underlying database is a Key / Value database but before a SQL statement is executed Value is serialised and deserialised for lets say for UPDATE statements.

I could not find in the documentation about which serialisation technology is used or I have an option to change it or not (like to Avro, Protobuf, etc..)..

And secondly, for the following Table structure.

```
TableA
  id BIGINT PK
  name STRING
  department STRING

TableB
  id BIGINT PK
  tableAreference BIGINT FK
  state STRING
```

If I execute the following SQL

```
UPDATE TableB SET state = 'DELETED' WHERE tableAreference = 9999
```

would not be that extremely inefficient. How much performance penalty I would experience let's say compared to a relational database Postgres.

The reason I ask, we are using in our projects Apache Cassandra, naturally having a database with the horizontal scaling capabilities of a Key / Value database and Relational SQL capabilities is extremely attractive but what would be performance comparison for such a scenario compared to Postgres, or I just should evade such a scenario?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding serialization, this overhead is minimal for encoding the key for lookup when compared to other databases. Performance considerations and inefficiencies in comparison to Cassandra/Postgres would rather come from consistency guarantees rather than encoding.

The exact difference in performance would likely depend on your workload, and there are several benchmarks you could take a look at to get a bit more information. You could also take take a look at some comparison benchmarks and when to use each database like this one on [CockroachDB vs Cassandra](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/guides/cockroachdb-cassandra/).

If you're interested in more specifics of the Key-Value store, in CockroachDB, we use SSTs with Log-structured Merge-trees. There are some helpful docs on how data storage is managed in Pebble here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/architecture/storage-layer.html#ssts